# Seleniumの要素を特定しているnameの取得方法が分からない？

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

こちらのQiita記事を参考にSeleniumの勉強をしています。
Ubuntu、Python3、Chromeを使っています。
以下のサンプルコードについて質門です。

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

上のコードは正常に動作し、Googleで検索が行われた画面をスクリーンショットしました。

この、

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
```

という部分は、Googleの検索ボックスを`<input name="q">`という手がかりで特定していると思いますが、この"q"というnameの探し方が分かりません。

www.google.comにおいて検索ボックスを右クリックしてInspectを選択すると、以下の図のように要素が選択されます。

[![Googleの検索ボックスをインスペクトした][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzZOv.png

```
<input id="input" type="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" aria-live="polite">
```

ここにはnameアトリビュートがありません。
この前後の表示をnameや"q"で検索したのですが、この要素に該当するものはなかったと思います。

また、`id="input"`で引っかけようと思って

```
#search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("input")
```

とコードを書き換えてみると

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="input"]"}
```

とエラーが出て止まってしまいました。

ということで、このGoogleの検索ボックスを特定する"q"というnameの割り出し方について、ご教示くださるようお願いいたします。

Comment: Chrome の lazy loading が関係しているのではないでしょうか。`chrome://new-tab-page/lazy_load.js` を見ますと、`URLSearchParams;searchParams.append("q",this.finalResult_);` という処理が見つかります。一方、FireFox で inspect すると `<input class="gLFyf gsfi" ... name="q" ... title="検索" ...>` と表示されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
おっしゃるとおりのようですね。
Firefoxだと取得できるということで、私の目的にはかないます。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: コメント欄は回答欄ではないです。自己回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントをいただきました。

- Chromeの場合、lazy loadingが働いているのではないか。chrome://new-tab-page/lazy_load.js を見ますと、URLSearchParams;searchParams.append("q",this.finalResult_);と書かれている
- FirefoxでInspectすると<input class="gLFyf gsfi" ... name="q" ... title="検索" ...> と表示される

確かにFirefoxでInspectされるとname="q"が確認できたので、私としてはこれで問題解決とします。ありがとうございました。